# Sending mail from c# fails over proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, visual-studio-2012, proxy

The following is my code to send a mail over a http proxy. I have set my proxy to the same as mentioned. Now when I try to run the program, after some time it says *System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved. May I know where I am going wrong?

```
protected void mailto(string message)
    {
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("10.1.1.4", 8080);
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to_address");
            mail.Subject = "For Data Using";
            mail.Body = message;
            SmtpServer.Port = 465;// Tried even with 587, but no luck
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            Debug.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "message sent");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Message not sent" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue with sending a mail from c# using Gmail SMTP, the problem was the Port.
Try to use the port : 587

```
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
```

Also don't forget to Enable POP & IMAP Access to your Gmail account, go to settings , choose 'Forwarding and POP/IMAP' from the tabs and enable the POP & IMAP

Comment: Yeah I tried. But still the result is same. couldn't send mail.